# Matrices that achieve worst-case $LDL^T$ element growth

Tags: linear-algebra, saddlepoint

Matrices that achieve the worst case $\rho_n = 2^{n-1}$ element growth in LU factorization with partial pivoting are known; see e.g. Theorem 9.7 in

*Higham, Nicholas J.*, [**Accuracy and stability of numerical algorithms.**](https://doi.org/10.1137/1.9780898718027), Philadelphia, PA: SIAM. xxx, 680 p. (2002). [ZBL1011.65010](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1011.65010).

Similar element growth bounds are known for $LDL^T$ factorization of symmetric indefinite matrices; for instance with Bunch--Parlett (i.e., symmetric complete) pivoting one has $\rho_n \leq 2.57^{n-1}$. Are matrices that achieve this worst-case bound known in practice? I am not looking for a complete characterization, even just one example (depending on $n$) that reaches the worst-case bound is sufficient.

EDIT: a remark in the same book shows that no explicit example was known in 2002; this is left as a "research problem" (Problem 11.10).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With some googling, I found

*Fang, Haw-Ren; O’Leary, Dianne P.*, [**Stable factorizations of symmetric tridiagonal and triadic matrices**](https://doi.org/10.1137/050636280), SIAM J. Matrix Anal. Appl. 28, No. 2, 576-595 (2006). [ZBL1116.65035](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1116.65035).

where they show an example that produces $\rho(A) = 2.57^{n-2}$, so quite close to the optimal bound; it is a matrix with $A_{ij}=1$ for $i\neq j$, $A_{11} = -\alpha:=-\frac{1+\sqrt{17}}{8}$, and $A_{k+1,k+1} = 4\alpha A_{k,k}-\frac{1}{\alpha}$ for $k\geq 1$.